# No idea what I did to DNS lookup for Github Pages site

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cname, a-records

I'm unfortunately not very sure what it was I did, but unfortunately, I can't get my Github Pages site to work. When I read the parts about having a custom domain, I initially thought they meant you had to use a 3rd party DNS host to have a the custom domain. The domain I'm attempting to use (for a personal resume/portfolio) is [leesavide.io](http://leesavide.io), since it'd be easier to get to than [leesavide.github.io](http://leesavide.github.io). I'm not sure how, but now the following things happen:

- `leesavide.io` redirects to `leesavide.com`, then redirects back to `leesavide.io`. I don't want a .com domain,
  and I'm not sure how I'm getting this redirect. I do have an account
  with www.namecheap.com, which will be closed
  and have any CNAME or A records deleted as soon as support answers
  the ticket.
- `leesavide.github.io` also redirects to `leesavide.com`. This is my biggest problem, as I'm unsure how or why it unregistered the domain from Github's default hosting.

Any help and suggestions are welcome. :< Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To unregister the custom domain from Github Pages, you need to delete the `CNAME` file in the Github Pages repository